# The org.apache.felix.gogo.commands missing requirement while installing a featue

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I'm using Karaf 4.2.16. I want to install a feature: `karaf@mst-ica()> feature:install my_feature.config` and get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve root: 
    missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; 
    osgi.identity=my_feature.config; 
    type=karaf.feature; 
    version="[4.0.0.SNAPSHOT,4.0.0.SNAPSHOT]"; 
    filter:="(&(osgi.identity=my_feature.config)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=4.0.0.SNAPSHOT)(version<=4.0.0.SNAPSHOT))" 
    [
        caused by: Unable to resolve my_feature.config/4.0.0.SNAPSHOT: 
        missing requirement [my_feature.config/4.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; 
        osgi.identity=my_feature.commands; 
        type=osgi.bundle; 
        version="[4.0.0.SNAPSHOT,4.0.0.SNAPSHOT]"; 
        resolution:=mandatory 
        [
            caused by: Unable to resolve my_feature.commands/4.0.0.SNAPSHOT: 
                missing requirement [my_feature.commands/4.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; 
                filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.gogo.commands)(version>=0.17.0)(!(version>=1.0.0)))"
        ]
    ]
```

I'm using Equinox as a system framework:

```
karaf@mst-ica()> system:framework
Current OSGi framework is equinox
```

However, it was not a problem with Karaf 2.2.0 and my feature I'm trying to install was working fine.

What can I do to have Felix gogo commands available? Do I need to install a specific feature first?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed. As mentioned in [Update Notes (from 2.x to 3.x)](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/update-notes.html), org.apache.felix.gogo.commands was replaced with org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.

> In term of development, the previously shell anotations provided by the org.apache.felix.gogo.commands* package (@Command, @Argument, etc) are now deprecated. Apache Karaf 3.0.0 still supports these annotations, but we encourage the users to upgrade to the new package org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.

I have changed my pom file and Java imports and rebuilt the feature. Also, I have installed shell-compat using `karaf@mst-ica()> feature:install shell-compat`.

After all of that had been done, I was able to install my feature with no errors.